# Is it a hardware error for the audio device

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, hardware-failure

Last night, after I restart my laptop   ( DELL Inspiron 14 N5010 )  the audio device is gone and it says no speakers or head phones are plugged in .

I've tried uninstall the audio device in the device manager which is showing the yellow mark as shown  in the picture and then

I  tried to install  my model's audio driver  ( from utilities and driver cd which came with laptop ) / also downloaded from the dell.com website but it said the hardware detected is not supported by this IDT software package.

And I see a This device cannot start (code 10) error . Can anyone help me about this ......I've been crazy looking for the solution !?

I m uploading s screenshot of the errors

http://s29.postimg.org/fthd5tebr/led.png

Comment: Have you tried Driver Booster before. Download it from the link - http://www.filehorse.com/download-driver-booster/  Then install it and allow it to scan your laptop. If it shows an update to your Audio controllers or any Audio related thing, just download all that. It will install automatically. After installation your problem  will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd delete the flagged 'High Definition Audio Controller', and if you only have one audio output device or controller on your machine, meaning no onboard as well as peripheral based audio devices, delete the other 'High Definition Audio Controller' as well, from your 'Device Manager'. Then restart Windows, it should be able to re-install the latest hardware drivers as well as any relative software when your boot back up.

Comment: problem still persists